# Visible jump before js runs

Tags: javascript

I've written a script that takes an unordered list and turns it in to an accordion. As the page loads I notice that before the JS has run the list still shows as normal for a second or two and then is formatted in to the accordion by the js. I can't edit the CSS to hide the list and the show it once js loads because I want to provide an alternative for users without js.

I'm running the function on page load.

Is there anything I can do in this situation? I can't think of a good way to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because $(document).ready() waits for the HTML to be rendered before executing the code inside.

You could potentially move your accordion init to be RIGHT after the `<ul>`

i.e.

```
<ul class="accordion">
   <li>Accordion Item</li>
   <li>Accordion Item</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".accordion").accordion();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Marko, Many thanks for the answer. It works a treat. Don't know why I didn't think of it! Oh I'm not actually using jQuery, just bog-standard JS ;)